# Why can't my rake task connect to my MySQL instance during a test run?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec

**TL;DR**

Why does this `mysqldump` rake task successfully connect to MySQL and finish executing when I run it directly in the terminal (in both development environment and with `RAILS_ENV=test` prefix), but not when I run it inside of an RSpec test?

**Long Version**

I have a Rails app with the following new rake task:

```
EXCLUDED_TABLES = %w(
  google_oauth_tokens
  intuit_oauth_tokens
  oauth_access_grants
  oauth_access_tokens
  oauth_applications
  oauth_openid_requests
  qbwc_sessions
  tokens
)

namespace :db do
  desc "Export all tables in the DB except for ones we specify into a compressed file that can be pulled down onto a developer's local machine"
  task :export_allowed_tables => :environment do
    directory = File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'dump')
    FileUtils.mkdir directory unless File.exists?(directory)
    db = YAML::load( File.open( File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'database.yml') ) )[ Rails.env ]
    filename_to_use = File.join( directory, "#{Rails.env}_allowlisted_#{DateTime.now.to_s}.sql" )

    username_flag = "-u #{ERB.new(db['username']).result}"
    password_flag = "-p#{ERB.new(db['password']).result}"
    excluded_tables_flag = EXCLUDED_TABLES.map{|table| "--ignore-table=#{ERB.new(db['database']).result}.#{table}"}.join(" ")
    database_param = "#{ERB.new(db['database']).result}"

    command = "mysqldump -v #{username_flag} #{password_flag} #{excluded_tables_flag} #{database_param} > #{filename} | gzip > #{filename}.gz"

    sh command
  end
```

I also have the following test to ensure my rake task works as expected:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'rake db:export_allowed_tables' do
  after do
    files = Dir.glob("db/dump/*allowlisted*.sql")
    files.each do |file|
      expect(File.delete(file)).to eq 1
    end
  end

  it 'exports the expected data' do
    test_full_name = 'Foo Bar Baz Test User'
    test_user = FactoryBot.create(:user, full_name: test_full_name)

    expect(Dir.glob("db/dump/*.sql")).to be_empty

    MyApp::Application.load_tasks
    Rake::Task['db:export_allowed_tables'].invoke

    expect(Dir.glob("db/dump/*.sql")).not_to be_empty
  end
end
```

The task works fine when I run `rake db:export_allowed_tables`, and it even works fine when I prefix the command with `RAILS_ENV=test`.  My SQL file shows up as expected, with 7000+ lines of code ending in `Dump completed on 2020-05-22  8:44:29`, and in my terminal the script starts off with:

```
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
-- Connecting to localhost...
-- Retrieving table structure for table access_control_analytics_reports_claims...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
...
```

However, when I run my spec file, the script hangs on the following line:

```
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
-- Connecting to localhost...
```

And while the .sql file is created in the expected folder, it's empty when I open it (which is to be expected if a connection to localhost failed).

I'm also able to open my Rails console in the terminal (again, both with and without the `RAILS_ENV=test` prefix) and execute the following without any problems connecting to localhost:

```
MyApp::Application.load_tasks
Rake::Task['db:export_allowed_tables'].invoke
```

I am able to create that instance of User, so I know the test environment database is up and running.  And I'm able to run the rake task even when MySQL is running, so it doesn't seem to be an issue of the MySQL port being in-use when I run the task.  What could be causing my test failure?

Here's my `database.yml` file, for reference:

```
default: &default
  adapter:   <%= ENV["MYAPP_DB_ADAPTER"] || "mysql2_annotator" %>
  username:  <%= ENV["DATABASE_USERNAME"] || ENV["MYSQL_USER"] || ENV['MYAPP_USER'] || [*FILTERED*] %>
  password:  <%= ENV["DATABASE_PASSWORD"] || ENV["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] || ENV['MYAPP_PASSWORD'] || [*FILTERED*] %>
  database:  <%= ENV['MYAPP_DB'] || ENV["DATABASE"] || ENV["MYSQL_DATABASE"] || "myapp_dev#{ENV['MYAPP_ENV_NUMBER']}" %>
  host:      <%= ENV["MYSQL_HOST"] || ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] || 'localhost' %>
  port:      <%= ENV['MYAPP_DB_PORT'] || ENV['DATABASE_PORT'] || ENV["MYSQL_PORT"] || 3306 %>
  encoding:  utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  strict:    true
  reconnect: true
  variables:
    sql_mode: "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
  pool: 20
  timeout: 20000
  checkout_timeout: 20

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['MYAPP_TEST_DB'] || "myapp_test" %><%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
```

Comment: Did you try this command with `--debug`? If so - what's the output when running from the spec?

Comment: @Grzegorz good catch, I did actually try that.  I installed MySQL with Homebrew, and apparently that disables debugging in MySQL by default.  When I run the above `mysqldump` command with the `--debug` flag included, I get "mysqldump: Option 'debug' used, but is disabled".  I Googled but was unable to find a solution to this so it became a roadblock.  If there's a known solution to this, I'm happy to attempt it.

Comment: This can be hard without `--debug` feature. What if you `puts command` before executing it? Maybe there's some weird difference comming from rspec?

Comment: I just ran the specs and the rake task itself using `puts` before `command`.  Apart from the difference in database names (i.e. `myapp_test` vs `myapp_development`) and the timestamps on the filenames, there doesn't appear to be a difference in the command syntax.

Comment: Sounds like the most promising strategy is to investigate how to install MySQL via Homebrew with the `--debug` flag in-place.  I'll take another stab at that.  Thanks for your comments @Grzegorz.